# Is my answer correct to this combinatorics question, "remainder of students taking units".

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have this question for a sample quiz, I don't know any other way to answer it as it's not explained in the book.
The question is:

> "In a faculty, there are 1300 students. Of these students, 300 are
>   taking a unit in mathematics, 500 are taking a unit in physics. There
>   are 150 students taking both a mathematics unit as well as a physics
>   unit. How many students in the faculty are not taking a unit in math
>   nor physics?"

Does my solution make sense to add the students that are taking a unit in math and physics, subtract the amount that are both taking a unit and is remainder the amount not taking a unit?
So would it be
$$300+500=800$$
$$800-150=650$$
Therefore,   $650/1300$ people aren't taking either units?

Does this make sense, it seems like too easy of a solution to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is quite correct, and the reasoning is correct. Formally:

If $M$ is the set of students taking maths, $P$ the students that take physics, and all students are $S$, then $M \cup P$ are the students that take one of them (or both), and $P \cap M$ is the set of students taking both. Then

$$|P \cup M| = |P| + |M| - |P \cap M| = 300 + 500 - 150 = 650$$

So there are $|S \setminus (P \cup M)| = |S| - |P \cup M| = 1300 - 650 = 650$ students taking none of them.

Comment: That makes it lot clearer, thanks.

Comment: @IceArt Glad to help. Part of maths is also learning to write convincing arguments. The counting formula was probably mentioned in your textbook as well? It helps to quote known formulae in the argument.